# How to expose afterClosed() method / observable from Modal Wrapper Service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm currently trying to teach myself coding and Angular by making a little app for myself. In my app I have made a wrapper service for the Angular Material ModalDialog. My app is a hybred of Angular and AngularJS (I've been working on this for some time).

The wrapper service looks like so:

```
export class ModalDialogWrapperService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private zone: NgZone) {
  }
  openWarningWindow(warning) {

    this.zone.run(() => {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
          data: warning,
          panelClass: 'dialog--warning'
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
          console.log('I need access to this');
        });
    });
  }
```

This is great an in a Angular Component I can raise the Modal simply by importing my service and calling the method like so, here is a Component Method that uses the service:

```
// component code
public raiseWarning(warning: any): void {
    this.modalDialogWrapperService.openWarningWindow({
      type: warning.type,
      id: warning.id,
      tags: warning.tags
    });
  }
```

This is great but I need to access when the Dialog is closed and the data it brings back. I can capture this in my service, see the `console.log` but I cannot access this in a Component. Should I add code in my component like

```
// component code
public raiseWarning(warning: any): void {
    const dialogRef = this.modalDialogWrapperService.openWarningWindow({
      type: warning.type,
      id: warning.id,
      tags: warning.tags
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
          console.log('I am in the component');
    });
  }
```

I get an undefined error, my question is, how do I expose the `afterClosed().subscribe` from my wrapper service to a component. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Do I need to `return` the `dialogRef` from the service like so?

```
openWarningWindow(warning) {

    this.zone.run(() => {
        // const dialogRef =
        return this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
          data: warning,
          panelClass: 'dialog--warning'
        });
    });
  }
```

I tried this with the amended Component Code, but it didn't work. I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see return statement from your openWarningWindow. I suspect this may be the case:

```
openWarningWindow(warning) {

return this.zone.run(() => {
    // const dialogRef =
    return this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
      data: warning,
      panelClass: 'dialog--warning'
    });
});
```

}

Comment: I have ammened this, and I seem to be able to catch the observable in my Component. I now just have to return data from the `WarningComponent` back to the component that called the service / raised the modal.